# Problemas a leer Texto : Latin A con php

Tags: php, utf-8

Tengo un problema con este Script de abajo la funciona que hace es buscar las almohadillas o **#** el `Hashtag` de un mensaje el problema esta en que no reconoce el texto **Latin A** - `UTF-8`, quiero que funcione pero no se como hacer el script o que función usar.

```
#ŞŞŞ no funciona este tipo de texto
#SSS pero esta si
```

Ejemplo del script:

```
function Hashtags($str)
{
  // Match the hashtags
  preg_match_all('/(^|[^a-z0-9_])#([a-z0-9_]+)/i', $str, $matchedHashtags);
  $hashtag = '';
  // For each hashtag, strip all characters but alnum
  if(!empty($matchedHashtags[0])) {
      foreach($matchedHashtags[0] as $match) {
          $hashtag .= preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]+/i", "", $match).',';
      }
  }
    //to remove last comma in a string
    return rtrim ($hashtag, ',');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solo tienes que adaptar un poco el *pattern* para admitir o restringir determinados caracteres.

Y en el *foreach* en vez de pasar la *key* 0 que contiene las almohadillas, pasas la *key* 1 que ha capturado los *hashtag* sin ellas.

```
function Hashtags($str)
{
    // Match the hashtags
    preg_match_all('/#([\S]+)/', $str, $matchedHashtags);
    $hashtag='';
    // For each hashtag, strip all characters but alnum
    if(!empty($matchedHashtags[0])) {
        foreach($matchedHashtags[1] as $match) {
            $hashtag.=$match . ',';
        }
    }

    //to remove last comma in a string
    return rtrim($hashtag, ',');
}

echo Hashtags('#SSS pero esta si');
# out: SSS

echo Hashtags('#ŞŞŞ no funciona este tipo de texto'); 
# ŞŞŞ

echo Hashtags('Con #SSŞŞŞSS$$$ no funciona este tipo de texto #SSS pero esta si'); 
# SSŞŞŞSS$$$,SSS
```

Si quieres restringir a ciertos caracteres los añades dentro de la captura del *pattern*. Ejemplos:

```
/#([\w]+)/ == [A-Za-z0-9_]
/#([\d]+)/ == [0-9]
/#([A-za-z0-9Ş]+)/
```

Si no me he equivocado al redactarlo debería dar las salidas comentadas.

> Edito el *pattern* con la sugerencia de *@Xerif*

Comment: Solo puntualizar de cara al op que si necesita que la salida contenga la # la incluya dentro de los parentesis de la expresión, es decir `/(#[\d\w\S]+)/`. Mis puntos.

Comment: @Xerif he pensado que no la necesita, puesto que la función original la elimina con _preg_replace_. Viendo eso, no capturarla ahora una función. Pero entiendo lo que quieres decir. Gracias por comentar y votar!

Comment: OscarR Igualmente creo que con `#[\S]+` seria suficiente ya que captura cualquier caracter que no sea un espacio. Aun que no se me dan muy bien las expresiones la verdad.

Comment: @Xerif tienes razón. Yo igual, me defiendo, más o menos.

Comment: ok la funcion, y perdon por la redundancia si me funciono los datos con # se separan y se suben a la base de datos en la campo #php_love. y gracias por la ayuda :)